# Typescript node express router and second argument. Typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

What should I do with function of registration to fix *@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises*. The one way I found how to fix this problem is write by eslint.

```
"@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [
  "error",
  {
    "checksVoidReturn": false
  }
]
```

But I'd like to solve this problem as so as eslint requires. Any ideas?

```
import PromiseRouter from "express-promise-router";
import { login, registration } from './authController';

const router = PromiseRouter();


> ESLint: Promise returned in function argument where a void return was
> expected.(@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises)

router.post('/registration', registration);
```

Here is full **function of registration**

```
export async function registration(req: TreqBodyReg, res: Response): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    const candidate = await ModelUser.findOne({ email }) as TuserFromDB;
    if (candidate) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: `There is user with email ${email}` });
      return;
    }
    const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 7);
    const user = new ModelUser({ email, password: hashPassword });
    await user.save();
    res.status(200).json({ message: `The user by email ${email} was successfully registered` });
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err });
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: not for a while(

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem using the default `Router` and solved it by doing this:

```js
router.get("/", function(request: Request, response: Response): void {
  void (async function(): Promise<void> {
    // do your asychronous work here
    response.json(/* put your payload here */);
  })();
});
```

I admit that I'm not fond of the extra boilerplate, but it's the best answer I've found so far.

The `(async function(): Promise<void> {...})();` part is just an asyncronous self-invoking function (note the extra `()` at the end).  The `void` in front of it drops the return type so that ESLint knows you really intend to ignore the returned promise.  Without it, you get a "no-floating-promises" error.  Of course, that means you are taking responsibility for using `try-catch` internally to deal with errors...

So, the end result with this approach is that the extra boilerplate allows you to to use async/await in the default Express Router.

Answer (score 1):

It's roundabout, but I solved the problem this way.

```
async function registerUser(req: TreqBodyReg, res: Response): Promise<void> {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const candidate = await ModelUser.findOne({ email }) as TuserFromDB;
  if (candidate) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: `There is user with email ${email}` });
    return;
  }
  const hashPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(password, 7);
  const user = new ModelUser({ email, password: hashPassword });
  await user.save();
  res.status(200).json({ message: `The user by email ${email} was successfully registered` });
}

export function registration(req: TreqBodyReg, res: Response): void {
  registerUser(req, res).catch((err: unknown) => {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err });
  });
}
```